# ¿Como añadir sonido en JS?

Tags: javascript, html

sé que se pueden hacer bastantes cosas en JS, juegos no es la excepción, sin embargo estoy consciente de que no es la mejor herramienta para hacer juegos...
Bueno he estado trabajando en base a un código del juego Snake que encontré por ahí y lo he estado “customizando” a mi gusto (así que si, no es del todo mío), sin embargo de las ultimas cosas que he querido poner es efectos de sonido, ya sea al moverte alguna dirección o tomar el objeto. (Saben a lo que me refiero si lo han jugado)
También quiero poner música de fondo y que esta se repita en bucle infinito (loop=true), si aprecian, lo hice en HTML, pero no funciona tan bien como quiero.
Y no sé si quieran dar alguna sugerencia, algunos me han dicho que un efecto para que parpadeara el "objeto". No es un proyecto muy serio, pero si quiero sacarme estas dudas.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/snake.ico"/>
    <meta name="author" content="TeamScrlet"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Canvas
      c=document.getElementById('c').getContext("2d");
      //**********************************************

      //Valor inicial de "Snake", declaro variables de puntaje de una partida y puntaje maximo.
      l=1;
      var source = 0;
      var sourceh = 0;
      //**********************************************

      //Definicion de cordenadas de "Snake"
      a=[{x:0,y:0}];
      xv=yv=0;
      //**********************************************

      //Funcion de teclas onkeydown, al estar una tecla abajo, pues reaccionara como ya sabemos
      window.onkeydown = function(e){
        e=e.keyCode;
        if(e==37){if(xv==1 && yv==0){}else{xv=-1;yv=0}}
        if(e==38){if(xv==0 && yv==1){}else{xv=0;yv=-1}}
        if(e==39){if(xv==-1 && yv==0){}else{xv=1;yv=0}}
        if(e==40){if(xv==0 && yv==-1){}else{xv=0;yv=1}}
      }
      //**********************************************

      //Funcion para mover el objeto aleatoriamente (el que busca "Snake" pues)
      function g(){
        f={
          x: Math.floor(Math.random()*15),
          y: Math.floor(Math.random()*15)
        } 
      }g();
      //**********************************************

      //Funcion muerte, colocarte en las coordenadas default, comparar tu puntaje con el maximo y colocarte 0 para la siguiente partida
      function death()
      {
        x=0; y=0; l=1; sourceh = Math.max(sourceh, source); source = 0; xv=yv=0;
      }
      //**********************************************

      //Aqui pues se define tu muerte si te sales de los limites, o si "Snake" choca consigo mismo
      function d(){
        x=a[0].x+xv;
        y=a[0].y+yv;
        if(x>14){death();}
        if(x<0){death();}
        if(y>14){death();}
        if(y<0){death();}
        a.unshift({x:x,y:y});
        for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
          if(x==a[i].x && y==a[i].y){death();}
        }
        //**********************************************

        //"Snake" crece si come el objeto y este cambia de posicion
        if(x==f.x && y==f.y){
          l++;
          source++;
          g();
        }
        //**********************************************

        //Esto basicamente actualiza cuando el jugador muere o este toma el objetom con esto coloca el puntaje actual del jugador y en dados casos en muerte solamente, coloca el puntaje maximo
        c.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        c.strokeRect(0,0,15*30,15*30);
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
          c.fillRect(a[i].x*30,a[i].y*30,25,25);
          $('#source').html("Tu marcador es: "+source);
          $('#sourceh').html("Tu marcador maximo es de: "+sourceh);
        }
        c.fillRect(f.x*30,f.y*30,25,25);
      }
      //**********************************************

      //La velocidad de "Snake", mientras el numero sea menor, mas rapido ira el "personaje"
      setInterval(d,100);
      //**********************************************
    </script>
<title>Snake the game.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <h2 id="source"></h2>
    <h2 id="sourceh"></h2>
  </form>

  <!--<embed src="BGM/fondo.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" width="1" height="0">-->
</body>
</html>
```